# Get the Checked checkbox in the RadListBox (telerik)

Tags: c#, asp.net, listbox, telerik

I am using RadListbox (Telerik) with checkbox. I want to get checked checkbox value from the listbox in the server side, please give best practice solution :

My code is :
**Aspx :**

```
 <telerik:RadListBox ID="rlbSecurity" runat="server"  CheckBoxes="true"  
                ShowCheckAll="true" Width="100%" SelectionMode="Single" 
                Skin="Office2010Silver" ></telerik:RadListBox>
```

**Code Behind :**

```
 string selectedCollateralId=string.Empty;
            if (rlbSecurity.Items.Count > 0)
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < rlbSecurity.Items.Count; i++)
                {
                    if (rlbSecurity.Items[i].Checked)
                    {
                         selectedCollateralId = rlbSecurity.Items[i].Value;

                    }
                }
            }
```

Comment: Doesn't what you have work?  I believe that is the correct way; the SelectedValues collection is also be populated only with checked items, I believe.

Comment: @BrianMains I am using loop for getting the single value, so I have some doubt this code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have **CheckBoxes="true"** and **SelectionMode="Single"**. It doesn't make sense.

The reason of displaying CheckBoxes is you allow user to select multiple items.

You have two options -

1. If **SelectionMode="Single"** *(Single is default value and you don't even need it)*, then remove both **CheckBoxes** and **ShowCheckAll**.
2. If **CheckBoxes="true"**, then remove **SelectionMode**.

Comment: @Win..I am not able to get the count of radlistbox checked item on server side. Can you guide me what am i doing wrong.
https://www.codeproject.com/Questions/5251617/Unable-to-find-radlistbox-on-ASP-NET-client-side-b